# GET data using requests than insert into DB2

Tags: python, db2

Currently I am trying to retrieve JSON data from an API and store it in a database. I am able to retrieve the JSON data as a list, and I am able to connect to and query the DB2 Database. My issue is that I can not figure out how to generate an INSERT statement for the data retrieved from the API. The application is only for short term personal use, so SQL Injection attacks are not a concern. So overall I need to generate an sql insert statement from a list. My current code is below, with the api url and info changed.

```
import ibm_db
import requests

ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=node1;HOSTNAME=100.100.100.100;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password;", "", "")

api_request = requests.get("http://api-url/resource?api_key=123456",
             auth=('user@api.com', 'password'))
api_code = api_request.status_code
api_data = api_request.json()

print(api_code)
print(api_data)
```

Comment: {"carId":"111142c0-c2dc-4498-8cb0-0cc9babdee56",
 "color":"Black",
 "type":"Sport",
 "rrfType":"Cab",
 "engineNumber":"234nb5",
 "level":{  
  "status":"Automatic",
  "highPercent":11,
  "lowPercent":11,
  "lastReportedAt":"2016-05-06T00:44:05Z"
 }},
{"carId":"e5c32b36-c4ec-4788-8e2d-236a6285859a",
"color":"Black",
"type":"Economy",
"rffType":"Bed",
"engineNumber":"MX-900NT",
 "level":{
          "status":"Manual",
         "highPercent":100,
  "lowPercent":100,
  "lastReportedAt":"2016-05-06T00:31:43Z"
 }},

Comment: This is the format of the Json data

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the format of the Json returned, and on what your table looks like. My first thought, though, is to use Python's json module:

```
import json
#...
#...
api_data = json.loads(api_request.json())
```

Now, you have a Python object you can access like normal:

```
api_data["key"][2]
```

for instance. You can itterate, slice, or do whatever else to extract the data you want. Say your json represented rows to be inserted:

```
query = "INSERT INTO <table> VALUES\n"
i = 0
for row in api_data:
  query += "(%s)" %([i for i in row])
  if i < len(api_data)-1: query += ",\n"
  i += 1
```

Again, this will vary greatly depending on the format of your table and JSON, but that's the general idea I'd start with.

Comment: Yes, great point, thanks. The OP said this is a one-time use, personal project, but even so, not passing values directly is a good habbit to get into.

Comment: This is working, but currently it is selecting only the column names. I need it to select the values. Is there a way to edit this so that it selects the values? Below is the list that the code is generating the values from: [{u'level': {u'status': u'Automatic', u'lastReportedAt': u'2016-05-09T06:37:26Z', u'lowPercent': 10, u'highPercent': 10}, u'color': u'Black', u'type': u'Economy', u'carId': u'319142c0-c2dc-4498-8cb0-0cc9babdee56', u'engineNumber': u'24B6035', u'rrfType': u'Cab'}

Comment: Also just to clarify the values are the second items in the list, so for instance at the begining of the list there is u'status':u'Automatic'. u'status' would be the column with u'Automatic' being the value.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to access the data differently. Try this: for i, j in jsonData.iteritems(): ... Now, i is the key and j is the value. Of course, you'll need to tune it to get the right items at the right times, but iteritems() should be what you're looking for.